# Can the user stop a long-running SharePoint search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

How does SharePoint 2010 (with FAST and without it) react when the user interrupts a long-running search operation (for example, by closing the browser window or pressing F5). Does it detect this and cancel the underlying SQL query or will it continue running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user clicks search and the server gets the request, the server will execute the request regardless of what the user does.  Even if you click stop or close the browser, the entire request will execute.  When the server tries to send back the response, it will see the connection has close and have nowhere to deliver the response, so it is dropped.